# What is the term for generalised code to handle cross system functionalities

Tags: programming-practices, terminology

I work in a codebase which handles two countries' energy market functionalities as- payment, energy consumption, billing statements, addresses etc.

For this I need to make sure that when I am writing a new feature the country1 code change doesn't break country2 code.

How is this activity called or how can I express this duty in a simple phrase?

Comment: I dared to slightly rephrase your question to keep it general enough, focus it on software engineering terminology, and decouple it from resume writing (which would make it a request fir an out of scope career related advice). I hope you don’t object. Some more infos could help to fine-tune the answers.

Answer (score 1):

In a broader sense, and regardless of how you did it, you ensure the [interoperability](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interoperability) of both code bases.

With the detail you provide, it’s not possible to provide more precise terms. But  what you describe:

- looks very similar to [context mapping](https://medium.com/ingeniouslysimple/context-mapping-in-domain-driven-design-9063465d2eb8)  in domain driven design, when working on a shared kernel (in other methodologies this is sometimes called a “core model”), partnering (for interoperability), or designing an anti-corruption layer to make sure that despite model evolution on both sides, the things continue to work together.
- or could simply be related to interfacing and API design.